# Collaborate on folder inside Dropbox public folder?

Tags: sync, dropbox, box.com

What is the best pattern for write enabled collaboration on a subfolder inside the **Dropbox public folder**?

The use case is that I want to give write access to multiple people, while giving the general public read only access.

I understand that I can't use Dropbox directly for this. When I try the «Share folder» feature, Dropbox responds:

> You can't create shared folders inside your Public folder.

So I tried to install **Box** for (the single purpose of) having that inside the Dropbox public folder. But changing the default location for the Box folder was unsuccessful, even though I followed [this guide on box.com](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200852947-How-Can-I-Change-the-Default-Folder-Location-for-Box-Sync-) (also after creating the plist file, the Box folder appeared in the default location).

So, have anyone been successful at this, and what pattern did you use?

Comment: Thread for [the same question](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=111862) in the Dropbox forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks, Wes! :-)

[Wes Sonnenreich posted a solution in 2012](http://sonnenreich.com/ramble/2012/02/sharing-dropbox-subfolders-it-is-possible/).

It requires command line tampering, so a bit more cumbersome than ideal. 
But in my experimentation so far, it works as I hoped. A colleague of mine now has write access to a subfolder inside the Public folder.